# row-level locks vs index record locks

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb, rowlocking

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-record-locks

> Record Locks
>
> A record lock is a lock on an **index record**. For example, SELECT c1
> FROM t WHERE c1 = 10 FOR UPDATE; prevents any other transaction from
> inserting, updating, or deleting rows where the value of t.c1 is 10.
>
> Record locks always lock **index records**, even if a table is defined
> with no indexes. For such cases, InnoDB creates a hidden clustered
> index and uses this index for record locking. See Section 15.6.2.1,
> “Clustered and Secondary Indexes”.

¿what's the difference?

Comment: Be aware that the `PRIMARY KEY` is an "index".

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Whether an index is explicit, a primary key, or hidden clustered, the record locks behave the same way.

Comment: hi @danblack, so does the explanation of HOW THE DIFFERENT LOCKING TYPES mentioned in the link also apply if the column HAS NO explicit INDEXES?

Comment: Yes, and for good usage of innodb with locking, try to always be explicit with a primary key.

Comment: Hi @danblack, The only difference between using indexes on a column or not is that with indexes there are less rows locked and without indexes you lock all the rows of the tables involved, right?

Comment: No, you lock all the applicable rows in all indexes, whether clustered (hidden or explict PK), or secondary indexes.